# dd commands internal working

Tags: command-line, usb, dd

How the dd command internally works?
Does it caches the data in copy operation?

I am testing usb pen drive for read and write speed operation.
but for the same block size and same file size it always show large difference in speed.

Comment: please replay ASAP? We are no employees to anyone asking questions here.

Comment: You can also just [read the source](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/coreutils-8.25.tar.xz).

Answer (score 1):

`dd` reads the amount of bytes mentioned in the `bs` parameter (default 512 bytes) from source on each `read(2)` call, and writes to the destination using `write(2)`.

There is no caching involved here, but some buffering could be involved here as the data is being written.